# I want to trim space and string from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

```
samplework['pH']=samplework['pH'].str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False).astype(float)
```

I tried this. but it change the values

DATA:

```
pH
6.80000 SIAc
8.00000 MAI
```

Desired Output:

```
pH
6.80000
8.00000
```

Comment: Is it always the words `SIAc` and `MAI` you want to remove, or could those words be anything`, or do you just need the values ?

Comment: I just need values. but when I run above code it extract number but number change its decimal place.

Comment: `(\d+)` doesn't match the decimal point. Do `([.\d]+)` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
samplework['pH']=samplework['pH'].str.split().str[0].astype(float)
```